# I'm trying to find the name of a song

Tags: theory

I'm trying to find the name of the song with the music video which has two guys in submarine. In the intro of the music video it goes through a names of the ocean layers and stop on one. The two guys do chores throughout video in sync. The song is very recent and it has Bongos playing in the very beginning. I'm desperate hence why I'm here.

Comment: Try asking on 'Music Fans'. It's an off-topic question here, that's why it's been closed.